# How do I remove a class from another element with using angularjs and without using jquery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in angularjs , I want to add a class to a `<div>` when the div is clicked, and then remove the class when I click on another `<div>` in my html file, how can i do that? I've tried many different ways, but can't solve the problem. For example, I've tried this.

```
<div class="mainMenu dashboard" ng-click="itemClicked($index);" ng-class="{ 'newMainMenu': $index == selectedIndex ,'newDashboard': $index == selectedIndex }">

<div class="closeElement" ng-click="itemClicked(-1)"></div>
```

and in controller i use this code

```
scope.selectedIndex = 0;

  $scope.itemClicked = function ($index) {
    console.log($index);
    $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
  }
```

another way that i test

```
<div class="mainMenu news " ng-click="flag = 1;" ng-class="{ 'newMainMenu': flag == 1 }">
```

how can I remove that class without using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where is my problem repeat the name of a controller isn't make a integrated scope  I can not using a value with same name in that area i must just use controller name  one time and put of code in one div

Answer (score 0):

altough you didn't show all of your code, here's a simple **[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DQsAKkjfuoqZGiuVJnvR?p=preview)** you can learn from:

you need to set a variable on the controller's $scope, set it to true/false when elements are clicked, and give the proper class to each element according to that variable's value

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.status = true;
});
```

and in your html:

```
<div ng-controller="DataCtrl">
  <form>
    <button type="button" ng-click="status = !status" class="btn btn-lg" ng-class="{'btn-success' : status, 'btn-danger' : !status}">
      1
    </button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="status = !status" class="btn btn-lg" ng-class="{'btn-danger' : status, 'btn-success' : !status}">
      2
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you'll need to show more code. even better make a plnkr (plnkr.co)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to implement a navigation menu, in the HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="m in menus" ng-class="{selected:m==selectedItem}" ng-click="selectedItem=m">{{m}}</li>
</ul>
```

and in the the scope

```
$scope.menus = ["Home", "Contact", "Location"]
```